# issue with Cross Bu query from parent BU

Tags: marketing-cloud

i'm wondering if there is a way to do a cross BU query for a mobile tracking, and in the query to have a field with the MID and also the name of the BU (we have 1 parent and 3 daughter BU).

Is this possible?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Mobile tracking is BU based. What I would do is query DataViews in each BU and store the results in the Shared Data Extensions folder (1 query = 1 DE). Hardcode the MID and name of each BU in each query. 
Make sure all business units have mutually access to these data extensions. 
Finally, use a query to agregate results in all previously generated Data Extensions.